# What does it means when MSE almost equal with labels' variance?

Tags: regression, variance, tensorflow, mse

I did a training for my dataset of 6000 images.

running np.var(train_data), I get 2435.

After training of enough epochs, my MSE is nearly 2415+-.

Is this means, that the model is unable to find any meaningful relationship between the features?

Thanks.

UPDATE:
My problem is actually try to measure the straight line in a image, in pixel. This is the sample:

[image]

And length: 153.2220610747682201

Training:

375/375 [==============================] - 8s 21ms/step - loss: 2458.0092 - mean_absolute_error: 41.0948 - mean_squared_error: 2458.0095 - val_loss: 2440.2387 - val_mean_absolute_error: 40.7302 - val_mean_squared_error: 2440.2383

model.predict():

[image]

As you see, the predicted values are flat at 110+-

What could possibly causing this? Can CNN not a right approach to solve this?

Comment: If you put your code over on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), I'd bet that someone can help you make it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the training was stucked at a bad local minuma. After switched to Adagrad optimizer, the mse continue to drop.

The mse again stopped at a level, but at least when plot, it is a straight line.

Answer (score 4):

The variance is the MSE for the most basic possible model, which is the "always predict the mean model".

$$ MSE =\frac{1}{n} \sum ||y - \hat y||^2 $$

If our prediction, $\hat y$ is always just the mean, $\hat y = \bar y$, then we have

$$ MSE = \frac{1}{n} \sum ||y - \bar y||^2 $$

Which is [just the formula for variance in $y$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Discrete_random_variable).

So, if your model's MSE is comparable to the variance, then, by the metric you are probably *optimizing* the model against, your model is not better than the "always predict the mean" model.

Comment: A linear model is another good baseline.  That's [OLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares) for regression and [logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) for classification.

Comment: My problem is actually trying to measure a straight line in the image, in pixel. Using CNN seems to unable to learn the parameter.